# Express CORS hell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors

I'm having CORS issues with a very simple app, took me about 10 minutes to code it and I've spent hours trying to fix this CORS error.

The frontend, written in React, makes a POST request to the Express backend using `axios`.

`app.use(cors())` is called before the single route in my Express app.

And this is the `axios` request in my React app:

```js
(await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {username: username, password: password})).data.success
```

I'm getting this CORS error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at...`

[image]

> **OPTIONS request's header**
> [image]

> **POST request's header**
> [image]

Everything works fine on `localhost` though.

Express code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const createError       = require('http-errors');
const express           = require('express');
const cors              = require('cors');
const compression       = require('compression');
const app               = express();

app.use(cors({origin: "*", allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type']}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const params = req.body;
    if (params.username === process.env.USERNAME && params.password === process.env.PASSWORD)
        return res.json({success: true});
    else
        return res.status(401).json({success: false});
});

app.use((req, res, next) => next(createError(404)));
app.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT, () => console.log("Listening on port " + process.env.NODE_PORT));
```

**Current, not ideal, working solution:**

Use the machine's IP instead of `localhost`.

```js
(await axios.post("http://192.168.*.*:3000/login", {username: username, password: password})).data.success
```

Comment: Can you show express code

Comment: Just added it in the question @SeanLawton

Comment: You can either exclude the local domain or just use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) for development.

Comment: How can I exclude the local domain? @mamady

Comment: @Alexandre [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150051/how-to-enable-cors-nodejs-with-express) should help.

Comment: @mamady I already tried all that, OPTIONS and POST still choke with the same CORS error.

Comment: Fixed it by ditching `localhost` for my IP.

Comment: please provide the full cors error, CORS errors are very specific.

Comment: @KevinB `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 204.`

Comment: @KevinB `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

Comment: Huh, that's a new one for me, congratulations. MDN says that's a network error

Comment: Yep seen that, no idea where's the network error at though, and it is only being raised when I'm not on localhost. Anyway now it works fine even outside localhost since I changed the uri in the `axios` request.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

As can be gleaned from [the Axios source code](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/73e3bdb8835ba942096b662e9441f1d85ce4d484/lib/defaults.js#L81), when the second parameter to `post` is an object (which is the case, here), Axios sets the request's `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

[This header value is such as to cause the browser to trigger CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests). The server must then explicitly list `Content-Type` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header of the response to the preflight request; otherwise, CORS preflight will fail, resulting in a CORS error in your browser.

Note that the [default configuration](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/c49ca10e92ac07f98a3b06783d3e6ba0ea5b70c7/lib/index.js#L8) of the Express CORS middleware (which you are currently relying on) doesn't allow any headers.

### Solution

Explicitly allow `Content-Type` in your CORS configuration. You can do so with the `allowedHeaders` property of the [CORS middleware's configuration object](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options).

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work. Still getting the same CORS error as before using `localhost`. 

`app.use(cors({origin: "*", allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type']}));`

Comment: @Alexandre Ok but, at the very least, you do need to allow the `Content-Type` header; that much is clear. To give us more information, please edit your question and add screenshots of the preflight request and response from your browser's Network tab. Also add a screenshot of the CORS error from your browser's Console tab.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the CORS error and updated the current app configuration as suggested.

Comment: @Alexandre Your screenshots show the preflight and actual requests, but not the responses. We need both.

Comment: There aren't any responses for either request: `Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Failed)`. @jub0bs

Comment: If the actual (`POST`) request is sent by the browser, then CORS preflight must have succeeded, and there must have been a response to the preflight request.

Comment: This is the response for both the preflight and POST requests: `Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Failed)`.

Comment: There isn't anything else available. @jub0bs

Comment: @Alexandre `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: My bad, I deleted a line of code after going over and over it. The POST doesn't go through, CORS chokes on OPTIONS and the response is `No response data available for this request`. @jub0bs

Comment: Perhaps your server (or reverse proxy?) drops the connection when it receives `OPTIONS` requests. I'm really not sure. Difficult to tell what's going on.

Comment: Pretty weird indeed, why would it drop the connection only when the front calls the back using `localhost` instead of using the server's IP? I tried running the app on macOS Monterey, Kali and LUbuntu (the app will be running on a LUbuntu VM for production), same error on each OS. I'll keep using the machine's IP for now which seems to be the only working solution. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure your cors options. The origin can be a string or array which is a whitelist of the sources allowed to make requests. You can even handle it with a function if you need it to be dynamic. Also you can allow or disallow methods, validate credentials, etc. Check the [package readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Cors is a security mechanism to block any try between different domains. For example you have your backend in a domain like: https://wordpress.com and you want to fetch your frontend from your domain https://example.com this prevents that anyone can get access to your endpoints to steal information but this should not be your only security mechanism

```js
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET","POST"]
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Nope that's not it, `cors()` defaults to `{origin: "*"}` and handles preflight requests when not passed any options

Answer (score -1):

Use the machine IP instead of `localhost`.

```js
await axios.post("http://192.168.*.*:3000/login", {username: username, password: password})).data.success`
```

Comment: Why did this help? an IP vs a domain would still be a different origin, if neither are the same domain/port/protocol as the page sending the request.

Comment: @KevinB Indeed it would. But the error wasn't actually a CORS misconfiguration (at least, I don't think so). The front was calling the back using localhost. Hence, a CORS error was being raised  by the browser on each request. Changing localhost to the server's IP solved this issue. As you may have noticed I have no experience with CORS, thus I am not able to explain how this helped.

Comment: I see, it sounds like what happened then is by using the IP, you bypassed cors entirely by making it not necessary.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think I made cors unnecessary by using the IP. If it were made unnecessary, the `cors` configuration from the Express app could be deleted without a cors error being raised, but I still get a cors error after deleting the cors config: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.34:3000/login due to access control checks.`

Comment: I agree, i think you're right in terms of this is some form of misconfiguration somewhere unrelated to CORS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).